# Python: How to convert value in DF based on rule?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a Dataframe with a column full of strings like EURUSD, GBPUSD, CNYUSD and so on:

```
CCY
GBPUSD
EURUSD
CNYUSD
```

How can I convert all value in this Column from EURUSD to USDEUR, GBPUSD to USDGBP, etc., like this?

```
CCY
USDGBP
USDEUR
USDCNY
```

Comment: kindly add sample input data & sample output you wish to achieve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "How can I achieve it? (no in the exchange rate value but the words, EURUSD to USDEUR)" Well, what is the rule that tells you that `USDEUR` is the correct result for input `EURUSD`? What steps need to be taken in order to make that happen? How would you solve the problem with pen and paper? It is only possible to write code to solve tasks that you understand properly and can explain fully.

Comment: I see that you have titled the question: "How to convert value in DF based on rule?" It would be a good idea to say, explicitly, *in the question*, *what the rule is*. Don't make us guess. Also, please note the [edit] I made to ask the question clearly and avoid off-topic noise. This is how we like questions to look. Please read [ask] for more guidance, and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am new to here, will learn lessons on this. Again, thank you guys to simplify and standardized my question!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you mean. But if you want to create a new column with the same values you just do.

```
df['USDEUR']= df['EURUSD'].values
```

and if you want to rename the column you do

```
df.rename(columns = {'EURUSD':'USDEUR'}, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['CCY'] = df['CCY'].apply(lambda x: x[3:] + x[:3])
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

def convertCurrency(value):
    switch = {
        'EURUSD':'USDEUR',
        'GBPUSD': 'USDGBP',
        'CNYUSD': 'USDCNY'
    }
    return switch.get(value, 'invalid')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Currency':['EURUSD', 'GBPUSD', 'CNYUSD']})

df['Currency Converted'] = df['Currency'].apply(convertCurrency)
display(df)
```

Output:

```
    Currency    Currency Converted
0   EURUSD      USDEUR
1   GBPUSD      USDGBP
2   CNYUSD      USDCNY
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vectorial functions:

```
df['currency'] = df['currency'].str[3:]+df['currency'].str[:3]
```

Or, if you want a conditional replacement (move USD first **only if it is second**), use a regex:

```
df['currency'] = df['currency'].str.replace(r'(...)USD', r'USD\1', regex=True)
```

output:

```
  currency
0   USDEUR
1   USDGBP
2   USDCNY
```